# MVC4: How to show Group of checkboxes with header checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying display multiple group of checkboxes with header checkbox in view, like below image.
[image]

from database I get the data like this,

```
    CODE     SUBCODE       DESCR             DESCR              PrevOptIn
    GLOBAL   BOOKS         Books             Global products    True
    GLOBAL   ENERGY4ME     Energy            Global products    True
    GLOBAL   JOURNALS      Journals          Global products    True
    REGION   ASIA_PACIFIC  Asia Pacific      Geographical       False
    REGION   CANADA        Canada            Geographical       True
    REGION   EUROPE        Europe            Geographical       True
    SPECIAL  SALES         Promotional       Notices            False
    REGIONAL PROGRAMS      Conferences       Events             False
    REGIONAL COURSES       Training courses  Events             False
    REGIONAL EVENTS        Web events        Events             True
```

When I clicked on header checkbox below of that header group of checkboxes should check/uncheck.

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index(string cusId = null, 
        string emailId = null, string marketoId=null )
            {

    _custCommPref.CustomerId = cusId;
    _custCommPref.MarketId = marketId;

    _lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
        ((from a in _dbEntitiesA.APP_SUBCODE.Where(x => x.TYPE == "OPT_IN" &&
 x.ACTIVE_FLAG == "Y")
          join appCode in _personifyEntities.APP_CODE
          on new { CODE = a.CODE, TYPE = a.TYPE } equals new { 
                   CODE = appCode.CODE, TYPE = appCode.TYPE }
          select new OptInInterestArea()
          {
               Code = a.CODE,
               SubCode = a.SUBCODE,
               SubCodeDescription = a.DESCR,
               CodeDescription = appCode.DESCR
         }).ToList());

         _lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
          (
              (from a in _lstOptInInterest
                join b in _dbEntitiesB.CustCommPreferences
                on new { CODE = a.Code, SUBCODE = a.SubCode } equals new { 
                         CODE = b.Code, SUBCODE = b.Subcode }
                into leftGroup
                from b in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new OptInInterestArea()
                {
                  Code = a.Code,
                  SubCode = a.SubCode,
                  SubCodeDescription = a.SubCodeDescription,
                  CodeDescription = a.CodeDescription,
                  PrevOptIn = b != null && b.OptedIn == true
               }).ToList()
            );

            _custCommPref.OptInInterestAreas = 
                    new List<OptInInterestArea>(_lstOptInInterest);
            return View(_custCommPref);
        }
```

I am stopped here to create view farther. Please suggested me.

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 4):

Create classes:

```
class CheckBoxGroup
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
    public List<CheckBoxItem> {get;set;}
}

class CheckBoxItem
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
}
```

Include property into general page model:

```
public List<CheckBoxGroup> CheckboxGroups
```

Implement EditorTemplate for types CheckBoxGroup and CheckBoxItem. And just call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CheckBoxGroups)
```

If you want to have some kind of client-side behavior like when parent checked all the children also get checked - you will need to write some JavaScript.